# Weird behaviour of connectTimeout in mysql Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, mysql-connector

I want to implement Database connection timeout in my spring boot application so that whenever establishing connection to the Database takes more than a certain time, it should throw a timeout exception and it should not wait indefinetely. I am using mysql as database. In my JDBC URL I have mentioned the parameter "connectTimeout" like this:

`datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://XX.XX.XX.XX/dbName?connectTimeout=5000`

In the official docs, its mentioned that the unit is in milliseconds. Now I have measured the database connection time in my local to be around 1400ms.

```
stopwatch.start();
datasource.getConnection();
stopwatch.stop();
```

So ideally, setting connectTimeout to be less than 1000 should throw timeout exception. But it does not throw any error even after giving a value as low as 10.

Only when I mention the value to be 1, then it throws me timeout exception.

`datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://XX.XX.XX.XX/dbName?connectTimeout=1`

Which gives me the notion that maybe the timeout is being considered in seconds? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Mysql Connector Verion: 5.1.46

Docs Link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-networking.html

Comment: strange behave. you can also add `?sessionVariables=MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=123456666`check the reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-session.html#cj-conn-prop_sessionVariables